# How can I allow users without a registered account to submit to web to case?

Tags: salesforce

I am setting up a web to case form. Currently, it only allows users who are registered customers to submit cases. If you try to submit a case from an unregistered email, the case does not  show up in the admin area. I dug through the Salesforce documentation and didn't find anyway change this behavior and allow a user who is not registered as a customer to submit a case.

Is there any way for me to do this?

Answer (score 0):

[Web to Case](https://help.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=015300000036A6eAAE) should fulfill your requirement. It allows everyone to create a case in Salesforce, even those who are not users or contacts.

Answer (score 0):

> Build -> Customize -> Self Service -> Web-to-Case HTML Generator.

It works fine.